# In HTML “Chartreuse” is a color?

Tags: html, css, colors

Certain random strings in HTML can result in specific colors when used as background colors. For instance, when the attribute `bgcolor` is set to "Chartreuse," it generates a light green background:

Example: `<body bgcolor="Chartreuse"> test </body>`

In essence, these seemingly arbitrary strings trigger predefined color representations in HTML, influencing the appearance of the background.

Comment: Chartreuse is not a random string, it is the name for color #7fff00. The question has been closed as a duplicate of one discussing chucknorriss as a color. The chucknorriss explanation is fun and enlightening to some maybe, but has absolutely nothing to do with chartreuse being a sort of green in CSS.

Comment: So the question is essentially "why is the background chartreuse coloured when I set the background colour to chartreuse?"

Answer (score 1):

They are not random. They are actually part of the CSS specification - the Color Module specification to be accurate:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#svg-color

As you can find there, these names come from the X11 color names that were choosen arbitrarily during the 80s.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names